# If two page files are on separate disks, how do I set Windows to fill up one and then the other

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

I am running windows 7 in a virtual machine.

I have a C drive that is a normal SATA drive.  I have a virtio drive that has a Reizer file system underneath that is roughly 3 times as fast as the C drive.

The thing is that the virtio drive isn't available until the drivers load and I am thinking that is isn't immediately available.  Therefore during boot-up the C drive should contain a page-file for help with boot-up.  Then after bootup the virtio drive should be solely used.

How can I tell windows to prefer the virtio drive when it is available?